# Lighthouse Report says: Audit error: libUrl.parse is not a function

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

When I generate a lighthouse report on my web application, I get this error:

[image]

and when I click on the Learn More link, it throws me a 404 error page.

[image]

I also tried to google this error message, but I couldn't find anything related to this.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It is a known problem of the extension.

There is an opened issue in the [Github of the project](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/4794).